# Can we use dataflow if TLS is enabled in Postgresql instance in Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Can we use Dataflow for CDC if source which is Postgresql instance in Cloud SQL is enabled with TLS  certificate security. I wanted to use Datastream but seems there is limitation that if TLS is enabled on the source we can not use except for oracle database.

Thansk
Dinesh